# Assign multiple values from a single cell to multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to Excel-Vb. I basically want to extract multiple values from a single cell and assign it to multiple variables. For eg.,

A single cell in an excel contains value in the format (0.1:0.2:10). I need to assign these values in a cell to three different variables. My code should look something like this,

```
  Public DeviceInfo (Optional ByVal rng As Range = Nothing)

         If (Len(rng.Cells(1)) > 0 Then
            rng.Cells(1) = 'This is where I'm not sure how to delimit colon 
                            'in my cell  value and assign it to different 
                            'variables       
         End If

 End Sub
```

So ideally, the o/p should be the values in the cell 0.1, 0.2, 10 should assigned to Variable 1, variable2, variable3 respectively. Can someone help?

Comment: Why don't use the build in **Text to Column**?

Comment: `arr() = Split("0.1:0.2:10",":")` will give you an array with `arr(0) = 0.1`, `arr(1) = 0.2` and `arr(2) = 10`

Comment: Can this also be used when the values are dynamic? For eg the actual template for 0.1:0.2:10 is min:step:max. The ultimate aim is to enable the single cell with these values stored in three variables and perform some operation in a loop. Like if the cell contains (0.1:0.2:10, 10:1:20, 20:2:50, 50:5:300).  The array of values at the first instance should store arr(0) = 0.1, arr(1) = 0.2 and arr(2) = 10 and extract the output as 0.1,0.3,0.5,....10. and subsequently the same for 10:1:20.

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding of your problem, You can write code as below it works
you need to supply cell as range and position value like if (A1="0.1:0.2:10")

```
=DeviceInfo(A1,0)'output is 0.1
=DeviceInfo(A1,1)'output is 0.2
=DeviceInfo(A1,2)'output is 10

'''
Public Function DeviceInfo(rng As Range, val As Integer)
'This function split string "0.1:0.2:10" on the basis of char ":"
'required input rng as informat of "0.1:0.2:10" and val as position of string after split

Dim LArray() As String 'Dim for output array

LArray = Split(rng.Value, ":") 'split on basis of ":" char

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(val) = True Then

DeviceInfo = LArray(val)

Else
DeviceInfo = "Not Number"

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can this also be used when the values are dynamic? For eg the actual template for 0.1:0.2:10 is min:step:max. The ultimate aim is to enable the single cell with these values stored in three variables and perform some operation in a loop. Like if the cell contains (0.1:0.2:10, 10:1:20, 20:2:50, 50:5:300). The array of values at the first instance should store arr(0) = 0.1, arr(1) = 0.2 and arr(2) = 10 and extract the output as 0.1,0.3,0.5,....10. and subsequently the same for 10:1:20.